# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'trainingID' before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, constants

How should i access data in my componentDidMount method? I have sent 'trainingID' into my component as so

```
<AthleteRegisterForm trainingID={this.props.match.params.trainingID}/>
```

and now i refer to it in my component as so:

```
class AthleteRegisterForm extends React.Component {

    trainingID = this.props.trainingID;

    state = {
        training: {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    const trainingID = trainingID;
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${trainingID}`)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    training: res.data
                });
            })
    }
```

> trainingID = this.props.trainingID

and under method i just call:

> const trainingID = trainingID;

What should i change?

Comment: Can I ask why you aren't just setting `const trainingID` to `this.props.trainingID` to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `trainingID` before initialization. It is correct. You have declared it with `const` in the componentDidMount hook and used in the class. You want to use it like:

```
class AthleteRegisterForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // this is necessary to use it on componentDidMount
    super(props)
    //...
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const trainingID = this.props.trainingID;
```

Comment: I don't want to bother, but maybe you have time to have one peak at my other question considering django templates. Thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/q/63141157/13132016